# What does VIP imply by "games in Korea were the best"?

Tags: squid-game

In **episode 07** of Squid Game Season 01, a set of VIPs arrive at the island to view the final set of games in person.

Amidst the discussions one of them comments **“The games in Korea were the best”**. The one we see is the one in South Korea itself, so why would he refer it as something that happens in a different country?

Answer (score 5):

It is unclear if these kinds of games are played elsewhere. If they are, and he has seen them, this comment makes perfect sense.

It's like me going to Burger King and proclaiming that BK makes the best burgers.

Comment: The old man said he gathered rich people to think about ideas on how to make fun. So maybe the VIPs take turns in organizing the game (we don't see records for every year too).

Answer (score 0):

### Remember, *Squid Game* is a series by Netflix. This could be a teaser for future seasons.

Netflix produced this foreign TV series. Not mini-series, *series*, so there should be more seasons. The ending of the first season strongly suggests that season 2 will also occur in South Korea, at least in part. Gi-hun and the police detective may both come back. The detective got his call out and we don't know if his videos and photos sent. It seems highly likely that the action will resume next season in Korea.

However, for the show to last a significant number of seasons, it will help to make the Squid Game conspiracy more far-reaching than just Korea. This will allow the characters to chase the villains around the globe and could create an opportunity for directors, writers, and actors from other countries to get in on the action.